# TFS difference between [merge] and [merge,branch]

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, merge

I have this branching structure in TFS 2013.
[image]

Now I had a folder already in my **Main** branch called Websites.

I added a project TestProject in my **Dev** branch under Websites folder.
Now when I merge Project from **Dev to Main** branch, it shows these in the pending Checking window.

[image]

There is **[merge]** next to Websites folder. I get that I am merging some stuff into Websites folder.

[image]

But for all other folders and documents I have in the project I added, it shows **[merge, branch]** above.

What does that 'branch' indicate and what is it's importance? Am I doing something wrong there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it just shows `[Merge]` then there was a previous relation between the source and the target file or folder.

If it shows `[Merge, Branch]` it means that a new relationship has been created. This was most likely a new file or folder in the source branch.

Comment: It confuses me as the Main is the parent and Dev is the child and was thinking it was doing something opposite.

Comment: Branch Relationships can be created even between two branches that have no relation. Every time you branch anything for the first time, TFS will register a Branch-relationship to support merges in the future.

Comment: Just trying to be sure it's not doing that baseless merge automatically.

Comment: It will, but that only happens when you manally type the target branch location when you merge. When you select a target branch from the drop-down, you will always pick a branch that has an existing `[branch]` relationship.